# Slide Activo por defecto en Acordeón

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy intentando hacer un acordeón para mostrar unas imágenes con CSS nada mas, sin embargo me gustaría que uno de las imágenes del acordeón estuviera activo por defecto.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".a3").addClass("active");
        $(".box").hover(function() {
            $(".box").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });

});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2');
html {
    height: 100vh;
}

.accordion {
    max-width: 990px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
    height: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: flex;
    box-shadow: 0px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47);
    flex-direction: row;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.box {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    background-position: left;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: .7s;
    box-shadow: 0px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47);
}


.active{
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        background-position: left;
        background-size: cover;
        transition: 1s;
        box-shadow: 0px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47);
        flex: 7;
        height: 800px;
}
    
.a1 {
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1516654/pexels-photo-1516654.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
}
.a2 {
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1056555/pexels-photo-1056555.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260")
}
.a3 {
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/129207/pexels-photo-129207.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
    color: #fff;
}
.a4 {
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/240038/pexels-photo-240038.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
    color: #fff;
}
.a5 {
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/220994/pexels-photo-220994.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"); 
}
p {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}
.text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
.box:hover .text{
    opacity:1;
}
h1 {
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 100px auto 20px auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    body{
        margin: 0;
    }
    .accordion {
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 700px;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    .box {
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    .box:hover {
        flex: 7;
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Accordion Slider</h1>

<div class="accordion">

    <!-- BOX 1 -->
    <div class="box a1">
        <div class="image_1">
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum iaculis nisl sed dictum aliquam.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- BOX 2 -->
    <div class="box a2">
        <div class="image_2">
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum iaculis nisl sed dictum aliquam.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- BOX 3 -->
    <div class="box a3">
        <div class="image_3">
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum iaculis nisl sed dictum aliquam.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- BOX 1 -->
    <div class="box a4">
        <div class="image_4">
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum iaculis nisl sed dictum aliquam.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- BOX 5 -->
    <div class="box a5">
        <div class="image_5">
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum iaculis nisl sed dictum aliquam.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Actualmente la clase `box` responde al `hover` modificando el `flex` de 1 a 7 para ver la imagen en su totalidad.

Me gustaria que la imagen Central se muestre activa por defecto, es decir con `flex:7;` he intentado agregarsela directamente en la etiqueta bajo `style="flex:7;"`  pero se muestra activa aun cuando hago `hover` sobre otra card.

Puedo hacer algo con javascript alguna `add.Class` o `remove.Class` ? Agradecería cualquier comentario.

Actualmente por defecto se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que ando buscado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDIT**
He agregado una nueva clase llamada `active` y he eliminado la clase `.box:hover` y con unas lineas de codigo javascript el query parece estar funcionando pero todas mis card con clase `.box` aparecen activas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno creo que el problema era que le estaba agregando la clase `active` a todas las cards y modifique el codigo para que por defecto la clase `active` se agregue unicamente a la clase `a3` que es donde quiero que se muestre por default.

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".a3").addClass("active");


        $(".box").hover(function() {
            $(".box").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });

    });
    </script>
```